# Active Record: Show Tables

Tags: add-on-development, module, codeigniter

Is there a codeigniter active record way of doing something like:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE exp_mytable"))==1)
```

I'm not seeing Show Tables as a method in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither Active Record nor DB Forge have a “SHOW TABLES” function. You’d have to just do it with `query()`:

```
if ($EE->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE `exp_mytable`')->num_rows())
```

Comment: ah sweet. so there is a built in workaround for those obscure queries. Thanks Brandon.